# Post function wont post the value

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying to create a simple post adder in Javascript. For some reason, it won't push my input. What am I doing wrong? Is there a better alternative to doing this?

```js
let posts = [];

function sendPost () {
    let post = document.getElementById("post").value;
  document.getElementById("postSender").innerHTML=(post);
}
```

```css
input {
  background: lightgrey;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  outline-width: 0;
}

::placeholder {
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">

<div>
<input type="text" placeholder="hi" id="post">
<button value="submit" @click="sendPost();"> Hi
</div>

<div id="postSender">

<p>
 
</p>

</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `@click` to `onClick` and change innerHTML value equal to your `let post`

```js
const posts = [];

function sendPost () {
    let HTML = '';
    let post = document.getElementById("post").value;
    posts.push(post);
    posts.forEach(function(item) {
      HTML += '<div>' + item + '</div>';
    });
    
    document.getElementById("postSender").innerHTML = HTML;
}
```

```css
input {
  background: lightgrey;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  outline-width: 0;
}

::placeholder {
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">

<div>
<input type="text" placeholder="hi" id="post">
<button value="submit" onClick="sendPost()"> Hi</button>
</div>

<div id="postSender"></div>

</div>
```

Edit: post added to posts array and displayed in separate divs

Comment: Yeah I just realised the @click.. Also, would it be possible, whenever I click submit it creates a unique  "postSender" div for each post?

Comment: @zyzzbruh check updated snippet, basically you can wrap any array data to any tag and set any attributes

Answer (score 0):

Update the @click to onclick and y create functions to grab the HTML elements.

Here is one way to do it:

```js
//function that grab te input value
function getInputValue(){
   return document.getElementById("post").value
}

//function that grab the div with id "postSender"
function getDivPostSender(){
   return document.getElementById("postSender")
}

function sendPost () {
   //create a ne p tag element
   let pEl = document.createElement('p')
   //Appends the p Tag to the div with id "postSender"
   getDivPostSender().appendChild(pEl)
   //Update the text on the p tag element.
   pEl.innerText = getInputValue()
}
```

```css
input {
  background: lightgrey;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  outline-width: 0;
}

::placeholder {
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
   <div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="hi" id="post">
      <button onclick="sendPost()">Submit</button>
   </div>
   <div id="postSender">
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

this line is wrong
let post = document.getElementById("post").value

it should be

let post = document.getElementById("postSender").value

Comment: How, if im grabbing the value of an input?